# SVN: File remains in conflict even after updating

Tags: svn

I can't figure out why I'm getting this message from SVN.  SVN is telling me a certain file is in conflict.  So I update the file …

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:didoclient davea$ svn up src/test/java/org/myco/myproject/dao/AccessCodeDAOTest.javaUpdating 'src/test/java/org/myco/myproject/dao/AccessCodeDAOTest.java':
At revision 27.
```

However, when I try and commit immediately after, I get the message that the file is still in conflict …

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:didoclient davea$ svn commit -m "… my message ..."
svn: E155015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155015: Aborting commit: '/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/didoclient/src/test/java/org/myco/myproject/dao/AccessCodeDAOTest.java' remains in conflict
```

What's going on?  How do I commit my files?  - Dave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone has made changes to this file that are conflicting with your changes. These might include changes to the same lines of code. SVN is not able, in most cases (if not all) to merge the changes, since they touch the same portion of the code. You **must** at least mark the conflicts as resolved, usually by fixing them, before committing any file to your repository.

You can copy the file with your changes somewhere else, then getting the latest version from your repository (you can do that by deleting your local copy and running `svn up` again) and then modifying the file you just got from your repo, adding your changes to it again.

There are some tools that might help in this process, like `tortoise-merge` for TortoiseSVN on Windows platform, but the technique used is always some sort of applying both changes (the one that is already on the repo **and** your changes) to the original file.

Comment: Technically you don't have to fix the in-file conflict - but you should do that. The more important part is to **mark the conflict as resolved** because SVN can not know if you have finished editing the conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You are right, if you don't mind I will update my answer with this note.

Answer (score 16):

The reason is a merge conflict in the  mentioned file.

svn resolved [filename-or-directory-that-gives-trouble]

Best,